Tried to develop an UI for Brain MRI image classification
I am using Google Colab python Notebook to develop the UI for my brain tumor classification demo frontend by importing streamlit, and run a app.py file for the interface. I am going to let the user choose which model that I had trained to classify the brain mri image. Below is my source code:
file = st.file_uploader("", type=["jpg", "png"])

ModelSelection = st.selectbox("Model to choose", ("CNN", "PDCNN", "Hybrid AlexNet-GRU"))

if st.button("Execute"):
  labels = ['glioma','meningioma','notumor','pituitary']

  if ModelSelection == "CNN" : 
    model_path = "cnn_model2.keras" 
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

    image = Image.open(file)
    st.image(image, use_container_width=True)

    # Preprocessing
    # image = cv2.imread(image,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    # image = np.array(cv2.medianBlur(image,3))
    image = np.array(image.resize((128,128)))

    prediction = model.predict(image)
    predicted_class_index = np.argmax(prediction)
    predicted_class = labels[predicted_class_index]
    confidence = prediction[0][predicted_class_index]

    st.write(f"Predicted Class: {predicted_class}")
    st.write("Confidence: {confidence:.2f}")   #Display confidence with 2 decimal

However, I had faced errors and didn't understand how to solve it. Below attachment is the errors:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call(). [1mInvalid input shape for input Tensor("sequential_1/Cast:0", shape=(32, 128, 3), dtype=float32). Expected shape (None, 128, 128, 3), but input has incompatible shape (32, 128, 3)[0m Arguments received by Sequential.call(): • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 128, 3), dtype=uint8) • training=False • mask=None
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/exec_code.py", line 88, in exec_func_with_error_handling
    result = func()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 579, in code_to_exec
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/content/app.py", line 65, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict(image)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 244, in _adjust_input_rank
    raise ValueError(

What is the main reason for the errors, I had look through the internet yet not able to be solve.
